# Having a hard time adding type <T> to list

Tags: c#, mysql, list, generics

I need help with my code as I can't seem to find the culprit of why adding type `<T>` to a list many times overwrites the other values being added.

Below is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string query, object parameters = null) where T : new()
{
    var lists = new List<T>();
    var ObjType = new T();
    var ObjProps = ObjType.GetType().GetProperties();
    int Objlen = ObjProps.Length;

    if (parameters == null)
    {
        DBConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlTransaction mysqlTransaction = DBConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, DBConnection))
                {
                    command.Transaction = mysqlTransaction;
                    using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dataReader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dataReader.Read())
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                                {
                                    var dataValue = dataReader.GetValue(i);
                                    ObjProps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == dataReader.GetName(i)).SetValue(ObjType, dataValue);
                                }
                                lists.Add(ObjType);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                mysqlTransaction.Rollback();
                DBConnection.Close();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (DBConnection != null)
                {
                    DBConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return lists;
}
```

I can't seem to find the logic error in my code. As I execute the code, the first add to lists are okay.

[image: First Lists Add]

But as soon as it iterates again for the for loop, the values seemed to be overwritten and I don't even have a clue as to why this is happening.

Below is the picture:

[image]

Any help/clarification/answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Delete all that and use Entity Framework. Avoid trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `var ObjType = new T();` should be inside the while loop and not at the top. Otherwise you are just modifying the same object and not adding new ones.

Comment: Thank you! :D
I was really unaware of that. Didn't know that when I add that type T to list I thought their value would be stored to what I say another reference since it's a list.

Answer (score 3):

You get the error because you are always setting the properties of the same instance and adding the same instance to the list.

Add `ObjType = new T();` before the `for` loop.

Comment: so I should always create a new instance to make it different?

Comment: Thank you. I was really unaware of that. is it really the norm if you add an object or type <t> to collections/lists/enumerables?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating a new `<T>` (ObjType) in your for loop. When you do, don't forget to reset `ObjProps` to reference the new `ObjType`.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my code now and it worked perfectly